# How to "group by" a series of overlapping point coordinates

Tags: sql, r, oracle, gis

I have a rather large (250k row) dataset that has a lot of overlapping point coordinates. I need to map these coordinates, but can only use a single point for each actually facility.

Essentially, i need to figure out a way to merge all of the differentiating data (Source code, formcode, WasteW) into each single facility.

Here is what my dataset looks raw
[image: raw data]

Here is how i would like it to look
[image: what i want it to look like]

I can use SQL (via an ORACLE database) to pull the raw data, or R or ArcGIS/Qgis to merge after the fact.

I ran a group by statement in SQL when pulling the code, but it only was able to provide the raw data shown below.

```
select distinct 
REPORTING.TONS, 
REPORTING.YEAR, 
REPORTING.NAME, 
REPORTING.ID,
REPORTING.source_code,
REPORTING.form_code,
REPORTING.primary_naics,
REPORTING.WASTEW
REPORTING.LAT
REPORTING.LON

from REPORTING where 1=1 and 
upper(REPORTING.REPORT_CYCLE) = 2017 
order by 
REPORTING.TONS, 
REPORTING.YEAR, 
REPORTING.NAME, 
REPORTING.ID,
REPORTING.source_code,
REPORTING.form_code,
REPORTING.primary_naics,
REPORTING.WASTEW
REPORTING.LAT
REPORTING.LON
```

UPDATED RESULT WITH NEW CODE FROM PARFAIT
[image]

RAW DATA:

```
| Tons | Year | Name     | ID           | SOURCE_CODE | FORM_CODE | primary_naics  | WASTEW | Lat       | Lon       |
| 0    | 2017 | Airborne | TN5210020140 | G11         | W801      | 928110 | N          | 36.611123 | -87.46234 |
| 0    | 2017 | Airborne | TN5210020140 | G13         | W101      | 928110 | Y          | 36.611123 | -87.46234 |
| 0    | 2017 | Airborne | TN5210020140 | G14         | W200      | 928110 | N          | 36.611123 | -87.46234 |
| 0    | 2017 | Airborne | TN5210020140 | G14         | W101      | 928110 | N          | 36.611123 | -87.46234 |
| 0    | 2017 | Airborne | TN5210020140 | G32         | W310      | 928110 | N          | 36.611123 | -87.46234 |
| 0    | 2017 | Century  | NVD980895338 | G01         | W001      | 562211 | N          | 39.61028  | -119.2031 |
| 0    | 2017 | Century  | NVD980895338 | G02         | W001      | 562211 | Y          | 39.61028  | -119.2031 |
| 0    | 2017 | Century  | NVD980895338 | G03         | W002      | 562211 | N          | 39.61028  | -119.2031 |
| 0    | 2017 | Century  | NVD980895338 | G03         | W004      | 562211 | N          | 39.61028  | -119.2031 |
| 0    | 2017 | Century  | NVD980895338 | G04         | W004      | 562211 | Y          | 39.61028  | -119.2031 |
```

NEW DATA FROM SQL PULL:

```
    +--------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------+-------+
| 6.874  | 2017 | FLINT HILLS RESOURCES ALASKA, LLC NORTH POLE TERMINAL | AKD000850701 |     G23     |      W609      | 424710 |   N   |
+--------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------+-------+
| 7.2015 | 2017 | FLINT HILLS RESOURCES ALASKA, LLC NORTH POLE TERMINAL | AKD000850701 | G19         | W609           | 424710 | N     |
| 10.333 | 2017 | FLINT HILLS RESOURCES ALASKA, LLC NORTH POLE TERMINAL | AKD000850701 | G19         | W319           | 424710 | N     |
| 0.05   | 2017 | SWANSON RIVER OIL PIPELINE                            | AKD035419795 | G19         | W310           | 486110 | N     |
| 3.242  | 2017 | SWANSON RIVER OIL PIPELINE                            | AKD035419795 | G07         | W002           | 486110 | N     |
| 0.0005 | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11,G11,G11 | W001,W004,W801 |  61131 | N,N,N |
| 0.001  | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11,G11,G11 | W001,W004,W801 |  61131 | N,N,N |
| 0.0015 | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11,G11     | W001,W801      |  61131 | N,N   |
| 0.0025 | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11         | W001           |  61131 | N     |
| 0.005  | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11,G11     | W001,W801      |  61131 | N,N   |
| 0.006  | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G22         | W001           |  61131 | N     |
| 0.0095 | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11         | W001           |  61131 | N     |
| 0.01   | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11         | W001           |  61131 | N     |
| 0.015  | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11         | W001           |  61131 | N     |
| 0.025  | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G09,G11,G15 | W001,W001,W002 |  61131 | N,N,N |
| 0.03   | 2017 | UNIVERSITY OF ALASKA FAIRBANKS                        | AKD048679567 | G11         | W001           |  61131 | N     |
+--------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Next time please provide your data as text to copy as opposed to an image.

Comment: @parfait edited original post to clarify. i am not a SQL expert so i am not sure how to use a group by statement  properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an actual aggregate query with `GROUP BY`, specifically using Oracle's [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm) for comma separated values in *source_code* and *form_code*. Run entire statement below in a R query call:

```sql
WITH wst_list AS (
    SELECT  Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", primary_naics,
            LISTAGG(WASTEW, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ID") AS WASTEW,
            Lat, Lon
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", WASTEW, primary_naics, Lat, Lon
          FROM "REPORTING")
    GROUP BY Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", primary_naics, Lat, Lon
),
 src_list AS (
    SELECT  Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", primary_naics,
            LISTAGG(SOURCE_CODE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ID") AS SOURCE_CODE,
            Lat, Lon
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", SOURCE_CODE, primary_naics, Lat, Lon
          FROM "REPORTING")
    GROUP BY Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", primary_naics, Lat, Lon
),
 frm_list AS (
    SELECT  Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", primary_naics,
            LISTAGG(FORM_CODE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ID") AS FORM_CODE,
            Lat, Lon
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", FORM_CODE, primary_naics, Lat, Lon
          FROM "REPORTING")
    GROUP BY Tons, "Year", "Name", "ID", primary_naics, Lat, Lon
)


SELECT *
FROM wst_list
NATURAL JOIN src_list
NATURAL JOIN frm_list
```

**Output**

```sql
╔═══╤══════╤══════╤══════════╤══════════════╤═══════════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╤════════╤════════════════════╤════════════════════════╗
║   │ TONS │ Year │ Name     │ ID           │ PRIMARY_NAICS │ LAT       │ LON       │ WASTEW │ SOURCE_CODE        │ FORM_CODE              ║
╠═══╪══════╪══════╪══════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════════════╣
║ 1 │ 0    │ 2017 │ Century  │ NVD980895338 │ 562211        │ 39,61028  │ -119,2031 │ N, Y   │ G01, G02, G03, G04 │ W001, W002, W004       ║
╟───┼──────┼──────┼──────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────────╢
║ 2 │ 0    │ 2017 │ Airborne │ TN5210020140 │ 928110        │ 36,611123 │ -87,46234 │ N, Y   │ G11, G13, G14, G32 │ W101, W200, W310, W801 ║
╚═══╧══════╧══════╧══════════╧══════════════╧═══════════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧════════╧════════════════════╧════════════════════════╝
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/JZIBH28657)

Comment: thanks for the help, i realized in my original SQL i accidentally left "BR_REPORTING" in the "from" and "upper" sections of the code. The reality is that its all just "REPORTING". I tried running your code (both versions even though I have oracle 18), and get an error saying "missing expression line 6 column 4". Is there any chance you can update your answer with my updated sql code? i tried just removing "BR_r" but its not working.

Comment: Because I use table aliases, simply replace all instances of `BR_REPORTING` with `REPORTING`, keeping `BR_r.` alias. If you also want to change this alias, replace all instances of `BR_r.` with `new_alias.` (keeping the period qualifier). See edit. But actually, I should have used `sub.` in outer query.

Comment: thanks for the help. still getting the missing expression line 6 col 4 error. looks like something is missing from the "from" statement that i cannot pinpoint

Comment: BR_r.REPORT_CYCLE is a numerical value (year) so yeah, the upper does seem redundant.

Comment: shoot! i want to say it worked but im getting a "missing WITHIN keyword" error at line 11 col 38. For what it is worth i am running this query in Oracle SQL developer

Comment: Wow thats so cool, it worked! So there is one little aspect i didnt think through fully. For the columns source_code and form_code, it displays EVERY value (so lots of duplicates). Is there anyway to just display the each unique value. So instead of "g01, g02, g02, g02, g06, g08, g08" its "g01, g02, g06, g08"? Added a photo to show whats going on. And thanks!! This is very neat

Comment: Really? The entire use of `DISTINCT` in both queries should have handled the repeats. I made sure to test: https://rextester.com/DNZH98579. Can you change screenshot to actual data to test? Be sure the `SELECT` (outside of `WITH()`) in first query sources as `FROM sub` (not `REPORTING`)

Comment: yes ok i was able to add a data sample to the original post. what do you mean "be sure the SELECT statement is outside of with()? There is no code that i am using that comes before "WITH sub AS"...

Comment: so taking a closer look at the data, it appears that the dataset is still providing duplicated "ID"s. I edited the main post with my RAW data and PULLED data to show whats going on

Comment: Not clear what the difference between both data pieces especially since records differ (e.g., Airborne vs Univ of Alaska). Is *PULLED* the result of this SQL solution? Regardless, I updated my solution to work with *RAW*. Turns out you need to separate the `LISTAGG` calls due to nature of data.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit unclear as to how you wish to combine the values in some of the columns - especially `WASTEW`, but here is a tidyverse approach to take your raw dataset and summarize it.

First we make some data to match your example data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

"Tons Year Name ID SOURCE_CODE FORM_CODE NAICS WASTEW Lat Lon
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G11 W801 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G13 Wl0l 928110 Y 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G14 W200 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G14 W603 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G16 W103 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G16 W310 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G22 W113 928110 Y 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G22 W219 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G32 W117 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G32 W301 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 101ST TN521002 G32 W310 928110 N 36.61112 -87.4623
 0 2017 21ST NVD9808 G12 W00l 562211 N 39.61028 -119.203
 0 2017 21ST NVD9808 G98 W00l 562211 Y 39.61028 -119.203
 0 2017 21ST NVD9808 G54 W002 562211 N 39.61028 -119.203
 0 2017 21ST NVD9808 G34 W004 562211 N 39.61028 -119.203
 0 2017 21ST NVD9808 G12 W004 562211 Y 39.61028 -119.203" %>% 
  read_table2() -> tbl.raw
```

Then we can group your data so that when we summarize the groups into single observations, the data is retained in they way you wished:

```
tbl.raw %>% 
  group_by(Tons, Year, Name, ID, NAICS, Lat, Lon) -> tbl.grouped
```

Next we can collapse the `SOURCE_CODE` and `FORM_CODE` variables within each group into a comma delimited form and also compute your desired `WASTEW` variable:

```
tbl.grouped %>% 
  summarize(SOURCE_CODE = paste(SOURCE_CODE, collapse = ", "), 
            FORM_CODE = paste(FORM_CODE, collapse = ", "), 
            WASTEW = case_when("N" %in% WASTEW & "Y" %in% WASTEW ~ "Y, N", 
                               "N" %in% WASTEW ~ "N", 
                               "Y" %in% WASTEW ~ "Y", 
                               TRUE ~ "")) -> tbl.summarized
```

Finally, we can remove the groupings and select out just the variables you wish to retain:

```
tbl.summarized %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Tons, Year, Name, ID, SOURCE_CODE, FORM_CODE, NAICS, WASTEW, Lat, Lon)
```

Comment: You could separate the parts for loading the data and the actual transformation to make your answer more concise.

Answer (score 0):

If You can use SQL then following SQL is the one which will give you the desired output.

```
SELECT
    TONS,
    YEAR,
    NAME,
    ID,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, SOURCE_CODE, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')
        ORDER BY
            SOURCE_CODE
    ).GETCLOBVAL(), ','), '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') AS SOURCE_CODE,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, FORM_CODE, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')
        ORDER BY
            FORM_CODE
    ).GETCLOBVAL(), ','), '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') AS FORM_CODE,
    NAICS,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, WASTEW, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')
        ORDER BY
            WASTEW
    ).GETCLOBVAL(), ','), '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') AS WASTEW,
    LAT,
    LON
FROM
    REPORTING
GROUP BY
    TONS,
    YEAR,
    NAME,
    ID,
    NAICS,
    LAT,
    LON;
```

**Note:** `REGEXP_REPLACE` is used to fetch the distinct values in aggregation as `LISTAGG with distinct` is coming in **Oracle 19c**.

Cheers!!